When is minimum potential energy in simple harmonic motion not zero?
We know that in simple harmonic motion, potential energy is minimum at the mean position and it is zero since displacement is zero. So what are some cases in which minimum potential energy is not zero? Does that even occur?

Energy has no absolute reference zero. The potential energy at zero displacement could be $0\,\rm J$, $1\,\rm J$, $10^9\,\rm J$, or $-10^9\,\rm J$ depending on where you set your (arbitrary) reference zero; it doesn’t matter in the slightest for evaluating the harmonic motion. The minimization (and curvature around that minimum) is what matters.

Potential energy can always be shifted by an arbitrary constant.  For a Hooke's Law spring, this means we can write $U=\frac12 k(x-x_0)^2+U_0$.
For a physical example, consider a mass on a vertical spring, with potential $U=\frac12 k(y-y_0)^2-mg(y-y_1)$.
You can show that the equations of motion are still simple harmonic motion, identical to the potential $U=\frac12 k(y-\bar y_0)^2 +\text{constant}$, with
$$
\bar y_0=y_0-\frac{mg}k
$$
being the "modified resting position" of the end of the spring.
